# xslt how to output highlighted code (at least in main languages)

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, syntax-highlighting

I have documents with excerpts of code inside the `<code>` tag of many language (it could be C, Ada, LaTeX, or whatever else).

The goal is to parse the code according to the language in the `language` attribute, in order to get syntax highlighting with CSS.

Also, how to avoid overlapping with XML syntax, like in the code bellow where "`<stdio.h>`" should not be interpreted as XML tag but as un C code?

###### The XML file

```xml
<code language="C">
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 printf("%s", "Hello World!\n");
 return 0;
}
</code>
```

###### Expected output

```html
<span class="PreProc">#include </span><span class="String">&lt;stdio.h&gt;</span>
<span class="Type">int</span> main(<span class="Type">void</span>)
{
 printf(<span class="String">&quot;</span><span class="SpecialChar">%s</span><span class="String">&quot;</span>, <span class="String">&quot;Hello World!</span><span class="SpecialChar">\n</span><span class="String">&quot;</span>);
 <span class="Statement">return</span> <span class="Number">0</span>;
}
```

For the moment, I find two possible solutions:

1. [XSLTHL](https://sourceforge.net/p/xslthl/wiki/Syntax%20Highlighters/) ;
2. The article [Using Pygments from XSLT](https://norman.walsh.name/2011/08/31/xsltPygments).

But both of them didn’t bring real usable example.

So how to make this kind of transformation?

##### Edit

As processor, I use xsltproc.

Comment: The `#include <stdio.h>` inside of an XML `<code>..</code>` element will simply not be parsed successfully by an XML parser and instead give a well-formedness violation. You can of course use a CDATA section to avoid that (or you need to escape the `<` as `&lt;`). As for the syntax highlighting, if the target is HTML in the browser, isn't it just possible to use a JavaScript syntax highlighter (like I think it is done here on StackOverflow)?

Comment: The goal is to avoid JS.

Comment: BTW, the `<` could be replaced by `&lt;` if their is absolutely no other solution.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use, which platform? Why is the detailed article on a Saxon extension not "brining real usable example"?

Comment: In terms of pure XSLT solutions, there is https://github.com/pgfearo/xmlspectrum, but you won't find support for C or Ada or LaTex there, XQuery is the supported non XML syntax.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I just said in the edit, I use xsltproc. And the article didn’t give a usable example because he didn’t bring a couple of summarized xml and xslt sheet.

Comment: Well, looking for an appropriate (syntax highlighting) library, whether in the context of XSLT or in the context of a specific XSLT processor like xsltproc, is not quite what StackOverflow is meant for.